# Is the memory allocated to a global static variable defined in cpp freed up after a instance of its class is deleted in C++?

Tags: c++, class, memory-leaks, static, global-variables

I have a class whose methods defined in example.cpp file and class defined in example.h. There is a static global pointer defined in a example.cpp file. (I need this pointer defined as a static global pointer in .cpp as it gets called in a static interrupt service routine running on a bare-metal system.) I am wondering **when a instance of this class is deleted, is the memory allocated to this static global pointer, defined outside of class (inside the cpp file as static global variable), freed up as well**? I am worrying about the memory leaking issue. (please don't suggest anything with smart pointer, thanks)

```
// example.cpp
#include <example.h>
static example* ptr;
example::example(){ prt = this; }
example::~example(){}

// example.h
class example
{
public:
example();
virtual ~example();
int a;
};

//main.c
void main(void)
{
  while(1){
           example eg1;
           delete &eg1;
           }
  //Has all the memory allocated to eg1 been freed up including the global static variable(a pointer)?
}
```

I understand that (int a) inside the object is definitely freed up once the object is deleted, but does memory allocated to the global static pointer itself (static example* ptr) get freed up as well? **(I assume) If the static global variable is not shared by all the instance of the class, does it actually allocate memory to this static global variable but not free up it after the instance is deleted? Is it going to cause a memory leaking?**

This is the first time I threw a question here. Sorry in advance if there is anything not clear.

Comment: Who not just use the singleton design pattern?

Comment: new and delete must be used in pair, now do you see what's your code problem?

Comment: I'm sure you're aware that your `delete &eg1` statement is both dangerously wrong and entirely unnecessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you run the code you posted, you get the following:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff560a8830: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

This is because you deleted `&eg1` without ever first allocating memory for it on the heap using `new`.

Second, the destructor/`delete` will only clean up memory associated with the `example` object. It has no obligation to clean up the `static example* ptr`.

Looking at this another way, destructors and `delete` are meant to clean up dynamically allocated data, i.e. data that lives on the heap rather than just on the stack of the current function call. In contrast, `static example* ptr` is a global, which lives on the global data segment, separate from the heap and the stack.

Thus, you can see that `delete` and the `example` object's destructor will not free the memory allocated to store the pointer itself, as neither have the jurisdiction to do so.

Edit ------------------

As others have stated as well, `static` variables live for the lifetime of the program, so they will not get deleted until your program terminates.

There is a lot to be gleaned here! `static` can be confusing at first, but a good knowledge of it goes a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Anything declared as `static` lives through the lifetime of the program. It is constructed before its first possible use, and destroyed at a not completely-specified moment during program termination (that is, after `main` returns or `exit` is called).

In addition, destroying a (non-smart) pointer *never* destroys the thing the pointer points to. You have to explicitly call `delete` on the pointer if you want to free the resources it points to. (Or use a smart pointer. Do. They're better.)

Comment: Thanks for answering but I might mislead you here. I am not interested in the memory of the pointer pointing to but actually the memory allocated to store the pointer itself. I just change the code a little bit to make it clearer.

Comment: @TyL: That was the subject of my first paragraph. The lifetime of anything static is the lifetime of the program, by definition.

Comment: Are you saying the static global variable is shared with all instances of this class as well? (I thought it only can be shared when it is defined inside a class as a member rather than outside of the class). Otherwise, the static variable would not know how many instances of this class I will created? Would you think the while(1) loop in my main.c will lead to a memory leak?

Comment: @tyl: There is only one static global variable. Why do you think it would be related to an instance of the class? It's just a global definition without external linkage.

Comment: Okay. I see now. Many Thanks!!!!!!! I kept thinking it will be created once an instance of it created....

Comment: The order of destruction of statics is not unspecified; it is in reverse order of construction. And it happens after `main` returns.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Yes, but the order of construction of statics in different translation units is not specified, and consequently neither is their destruction order. Perhaps "not completely specified" would have been more exact.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a static global variable is not a member variable, so when a class is allocated or deleted, there is no impact to the static global variable, unless class members explicitly allocate or deallocate memory for the static global variable.

In your example, you are simply assigning a pointer to the global variable, and not allocating new memory. Therefore, you need not explicitly free it.

Also, you need not call delete in main(), since eg1 is a local variable. When main returns, eg1's destructor will be automatically called.

Comment: Thanks. It's really helpful. Are you saying the static global variable is shared with all instances of this class as well? (I thought it only can be shared when it is defined in the class rather than outside of the class)

Comment: The static global variable is accessible to all instances of the class and will be over-written every-time a new example object is created. Even if that variable was made a static class member variable, it would get over-written in the same way. Therefore, instead of assigning the global variable in the class' constructor, assigning it to &eg1 in main() will ensure it does not get over-written.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** The `static` pointer object has no intrinsic link to the class `example`, and certainly no intrinsic link to the object `eg1`. If the system destroyed `ptr` just because `eg1` went out of scope, the language would be *very* broken.